# I have a git repo with some files in Large File Storage. How can I change what server these are stored in?

Tags: git, github, amazon-s3, git-lfs

I got Git LFS and set it up according to this website: https://git-lfs.github.com/

On one of my repos, I tracked a few large files, and that seemed to be working well.

I want to move my storage of these large files to an S3 bucket, and I found this project: https://github.com/meltingice/git-lfs-s3

I installed git-lfs-s3 according to the instructions on the README, set all the appropriate environment variables regarding S3 access, and changed my .gitconfig to reference the new server.

However, I'm not sure how to trigger the moving of my large files from the server I was on to the new server. Additionally, I tried tracking some files on another repo after I made this change, and the files were pushed into regular GitHub.

I tried looking at the git lfs logs through the command line, but they appeared to be empty.

What's the way to trigger the movement of this data? And is there anything else I can do to get more information about what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Since the files are already tracked by git-lfs, it should work if you just push them to another remote with the new lfs location inside your .gitconfig. Did you already try this out ?